# can't install mysql-devel on centos 6.5

Tags: mysql, centos6, percona

I need `mysql-devel` package to be installed on my CentOS 6.5 running Percona 5.5 (already installed & running).

When I try to install the devel package like this:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install mysql-devel
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Package: mysql-devel-5.5.37-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           Requires: real-mysql-libs(x86-32) = 5.5.37-1.el6.remi
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-32) = 5.5.36-1.el6.remi
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.37-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-32) = 5.5.37-1.el6.remi
Error: Package: mysql-5.5.37-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           Requires: real-mysql-libs(x86-32) = 5.5.37-1.el6.remi
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-32) = 5.5.36-1.el6.remi
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.37-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
               real-mysql-libs(x86-32) = 5.5.37-1.el6.remi
Error: mysql conflicts with Percona-Server-client-55-5.5.37-rel35.0.el6.i686
```

Here's what's currently installed on my server:

```
[root@server1 ~]# yum list installed | grep mysql
php-mysqlnd.i686                  5.4.29-1.el6.remi                    @remi

[root@server1 ~]# yum list installed | grep percona
Percona-Server-client-55.i686     5.5.37-rel35.0.el6                   @percona
Percona-Server-server-55.i686     5.5.37-rel35.0.el6                   @percona
Percona-Server-shared-55.i686     5.5.37-rel35.0.el6                   @percona
[root@server1 ~]#
```

Any ideas how to fix this dependency error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the packages provided by remi aren't compatible with the ones supplied by Percona. Fortunately it looks like Percona supply the packages too

```
yum list | grep percona | grep devel
Percona-SQL-devel-50.x86_64             5.0.92-b23.89.rhel6            percona
Percona-Server-devel-51.x86_64          5.1.73-rel14.11.603.rhel6      percona
Percona-Server-devel-55.x86_64          5.5.37-rel35.0.el6             percona
Percona-Server-devel-56.x86_64          5.6.17-rel65.0.el6             percona
Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-devel.x86_64     1:5.5.34-23.7.6.565.rhel6      percona
Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-devel-55.x86_64  1:5.5.37-25.10.756.el6         percona
Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-devel-56.x86_64  1:5.6.15-25.5.759.rhel6        percona
```

So you should be able to install the one you want e.g.

```
yum install Percona-Server-devel-55
```

Comment: `yum install Percona-Server-devel-55` did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I am now trying to compile an emulator from source code and getting this error `configure: error: MySQL not found or incompatible` even though the correct devel package is installed. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to install Percona Server-shared-compat

Answer (score 0):

in personal i install mysql use the community version from here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html and here https://www.zerostopbits.com/how-to-intall-mysql-5-6-on-centos-6-7/

for install mysql-devel i install of this way

```
yum install mysql-community-devel
```

and works, try again

Answer (score -1):

So the version of mysql-libs you're being offered doesn't reach the minimum version required by mysql-devel... I've just added the Remi repo to my server just to see what versions I am offered:

```
Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package               Arch          Version                  Repository   Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 mysql-devel           x86_64        5.5.37-1.el6.remi        remi        162 k
Installing for dependencies:
 compat-mysql51        x86_64        5.1.54-1.el6.remi        remi        1.4 M
Updating for dependencies:
 mysql                 x86_64        5.5.37-1.el6.remi        remi        5.8 M
 mysql-libs            x86_64        5.5.37-1.el6.remi        remi        776 k
 mysql-server          x86_64        5.5.37-1.el6.remi        remi         10 M
```

It looks there like the version available on remi is the version you need.

I'm not sure the difference between real-mysql-libs and mysql-libs but when I try to install real-mysql-libs I get offered mysql-libs.

I would recommend you try doing:

```
yum install mysql-libs
```

First and see if that can complete, if it can then try installing mysql-devel afterwards.

I suspect that Percona 5.5 relies on this older version of mysql-libs, in which case you might have trouble, and you might need to set it up on another machine if possible. Just out of interest what are you trying to achieve by installing mysql-devel? Do you need to compile something from source? Once I know that I might be able to suggest another way around the issue :)

Comment: no need to add remi mysql packages at all, because he has Percona already running.

Comment: All he was asking about was installing mysql-devel

Comment: oh, come on , read the question = Percona 5.5 (already installed & running)...

Comment: No it's not, the question is titled "can't install mysql-devel on centos 6.5" the opening line states "I need mysql-devel package to be installed on my CentOS 6.5 running Percona 5.5 (already installed & running)." He states twice that he needs mysql-devel installing, and never mentions anything to do with installing Percona-devel